# use the $q promise like the promise returned from $resource

Tags: angularjs, q, ngresource

With angular's $resource promise I am able assign the promise right back into a variable and use it with out having assign the results of the promise to the varible in a success function. I am wondering if I can achieve the same thing with $q?

Example

```
.service("rest", function($resource){
        return {
            user: $resource( "http://some.com/url")
        }
    })
    .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, rest){
        $scope.user = rest.user.get(); <-- This is what I want to be able to do with $q
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer: No

The `$resource` interface is specifically designed to allow for this kind of 'futures' behaviour. When you call `.get()` it returns a placeholder object that will be filled with data when it's available.

Because `$resource` is an internal Angular factory, it knows when to trigger digest cycles which makes it seem like you can use `$scope.user` from the beginning. In actuality, it won't be populated with data until there has been a HTTP response from the server.

A promise on the other hand, is a general purpose mechanism. It doesn't know what kind of placeholder object to store it's values in when they arrive. It doesn't what kind of values will arrive either. So promises expose a series of callback methods that we can use to let us know when the promise is ready.

---

### Long Answer: Sort Of (you can use promises to build interfaces that work like this)

This kind of mechanism only works because of the way Angular does its dirty checking on the scopes. When something asynchronous happens, something needs to let Angular know that it should be checking to see whether anything has changed and it needs to update it's views.

When data arrives from our HTTP response the `$resource` factory is responsible for letting Angular know. This means that the `$scope.user` object will show up in your view as soon as it arrives. `$resource` is responsible for making stuff happen when the async event occurs. In this case, the async event is the HTTP response arriving with the data.

When using promises, you are responsible for making stuff happen when the async event occurs. It would be for promises to be specific to Angular, so instead promises have a generic interface for dealing with the different async events that can happen to a promise. It's your job to do the work when one of them happens, which is why the short answer is no.

**However**, if you are implementing a factory/service/provider, for which this behaviour would be desirable, it is possible.

Let's make a rocket factory that creates instances of rockets, that will have their parts added later, in the same way that `$resource` does, using the `$q` factory.

```
app.factory('Rocket', function(Junkyard) {
  return function(name) {
    var rocket = {};

    rocket.name = name || 'Boring Rocket';
    rocket.parts = [];
    rocket.promise = Junkyard.getParts();

    // Junkyard.getParts returns a $q promise
    // which will be resolved with an object
    // of things that can be attached to the rocket.
    //
    // It might look something like this
    // [
    //   { name: "thrusters", "quantity":  3 },
    //   { name: "engines", "quantity": 100 },
    //   { name: "robots", "quantity": 2 }
    // ]

    rocket.promise.then(function(parts) {
      parts.forEach(function(part) {
        rocket.parts.push(part);
      });
    });

    return rocket;
  };
});
```

Now we can use our new factory in a similar kind of way to `$resource`:

```
function MyController($scope, Rocket) {
  $scope.rocket = Rocket('Top Rocket');
  // we can use $scope.rocket here!

  $scope.rocket.name = 'Even Better Rocket';
  // but it won't have the properties from
  // Junkyard.getParts yet.
}
```

And we can template these values straight into our views.

```
<section ng-controller='MyController'>
  <h1 ng-bind='rocket.name'></h1>
  <table>
    <th>
      <td>Name</td>
    </th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <tr ng-repeat='part in rocket.parts'>
      <td ng-bind='part.name'></td>
      <td ng-bind='part.description'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

As soon as the promise resolves, the properties will be added to the rocket and a scope digest will be triggered by `$q`, because `$q` knows that an async event just occurred.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate the detailed answer and the quick response! I will post any questions here. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The ability to assign promises directly to variables and render them in your template has been removed from Angular. See this breaking change: [Templates no longer automatically unwrap promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises). Instead you will have to assign the scope property in the callbacks when the promise has been resolved or rejected.

Comment: I don't think the question mentioned rendering promises in templates. It was more to do with how you can use a promise in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just return an object that gets updated instead of a promise. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csbarnes/amk8ybss/1/)

```
var getUser = function(base) {
    var user = base || {};

    // replace with actual request
    $timeout(function() {    
        // make sure to use angular.copy so the same object is used
        angular.copy({
            id: 1,
            username: 'anon',
            roles: [
                { id: 1, title: 'user' },
                { id: 2, title: 'admin' },
                { id: 3, title: 'editor' }
            ]
        }, user);
    }, 3000);
    return user;
};

$scope.user = getUser({roles: []});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this works (its a coffeescript),

```
service.getSomeData = () ->
    data = {}
    $http.get("/getSomeData").then (resp) ->
      angular.copy(resp.data, data)

   return data
```

In controller you can do this

```
 $scope.data = service.getSomeData()
```